# Subviews and buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a main ViewController:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

There i have a property with my ScreenView: `@property (strong,nonatomic) MUIScreenView* screenView;`

And it will called by:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   
    [self.view addSubview:_screenView];
}
```

Now take a look in my MUIScreenViewClass:

`@interface MUIScreenView : MUIView`

`@interface MUIView : UIView`

In my MUIScreenView i have a method:

```
-(void)addScreenObjectToView
{
   MUIButton *button = [[MUIButton alloc] initWithButtonModel:(ButtonModel*)MUIElement 
   [self addSubview:button];

   UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   myButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 220, 300, 40);
   [myButton setTitle:@"This is Standard UIButton!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubview:myButton];

}
```

And this is my MUIButton method to draw something:

```
-(void)addButtonToView
{
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 40);
    [myButton setTitle:@"This is a MUIButton!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:myButton];
}
```

And finally i have:

### [image]

How it's possible that **top button is dead**? if i touch on it nothing happend. I created it excatly the same way.

summarizing - what I currently display as a "This is a MUIButton!" is a View contains another View and in second view i have UIButton. 
as a "This is a Standard UIButton!" is a View contains UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to your main view controller's view to your subview and then add the button to that view. You can't call a selector on a different view and have the correct view receive it.